# maximum MAX_HEADER_SIZE under Jboss7.1.1.Final

Tags: jboss, server.xml

What is the maximum MAX_HEADER_SIZE value, we can set in Standalone.xml under Jboss7.1.1.Final?
I checked for data with size 5Mb,and it's accepting it.But is it having any maximumlength?